# How to integrate way2sms to my android app

Tags: java, android, sms, way2sms

I got the following Java API, but there is bug in the api.  It gives the exception as FILE NOT FOUND for the URL "http://wwwa.way2sms.com/FirstServletsms?custid="

Any suggestions?

```
public class SMS
{
    public void send(String uid, String pwd, String phone, String msg) throws IOException
    {
        if ((uid == null) || (uid.length() == 0))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User ID should be present.");
        }
        uid = URLEncoder.encode(uid, "UTF-8");

        if ((pwd == null) || (pwd.length() == 0))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password should be present.");
        }
        pwd = URLEncoder.encode(pwd, "UTF-8");

        if ((phone == null) || (phone.length() == 0))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least one phone number should be present.");
        }
        if ((msg == null) || (msg.length() == 0))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("SMS message should be present.");
        }
        msg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");

        Vector numbers = new Vector();

        if (phone.indexOf(59) >= 0)
        {
            String[] pharr = phone.split(";");
            for (String t : pharr)
                try {
                    numbers.add(Long.valueOf(t));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Give proper phone numbers.");
                }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                numbers.add(Long.valueOf(phone));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Give proper phone numbers.");
            }
        }

        if (numbers.size() == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("At least one proper phone number should be present to send SMS.");
        }
        String temp = "";
        String content = "username=" + uid + "&password=" + pwd;
        URL u = new URL("http://wwwa.way2sms.com/auth.cl");
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        uc.setDoOutput(true);
        uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.length()));
        uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://wwwg.way2sms.com//entry.jsp");
        uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream()), true);
        pw.print(content);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        String cookie = uc.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

        br.close();
        u = null;
        uc = null;


        for (Iterator localIterator = numbers.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext();)
        {
            long num = ((Long) localIterator.next()).longValue();

            content = "custid=undefined&HiddenAction=instantsms&Action=custfrom450000&login=&pass=&MobNo="+num+ "&textArea="+msg;
            u = new URL("http://site5.way2sms.com/FirstServletsms?custid=");


            uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            uc.setDoOutput(true);
            uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(content.getBytes().length));
            uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream()),true);
            pw.print(content);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            br.close();
            u = null;
            uc = null;

        }

        u = new URL("http://wwwa.way2sms.com/jsp/logout.jsp");
        uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        br.close();
        u = null;
        uc = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that URL does return 404 (after being redirected). Have you contacted the operator of the API?

Comment: Actually just now only i added comment there ,but haven't got any rply yet....if u have the updated api...would u like share it..it will b helpful for me...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the Url to ->http://wwwd.way2sms.com/FirstServletsms?custid="+number....Then it will work.